# Loading assets with AssetManager in LibGDX, Java

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a problem with some libgdx java code.
I am using assetmanager to load some textures.
Files are in android project, in assets/data folder, but when i try to load them like this:

```
manager.load("data/tile1.jpg", Texture.class);
```

it throws exceptions, which are basically like this:

```
Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/tile1.jpg
```

can someone please help?

EDIT: 
I post entire exception:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/tile1.jpg
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.handleTaskError(AssetManager.java:570)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:375)
at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.finishLoading(AssetManager.java:396)
at com.cyanstudios.onlinerpg.Game.create(Game.java:36)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load dependencies of asset: data/tile1.jpg
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:121)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.update(AssetLoadingTask.java:90)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.updateTask(AssetManager.java:498)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetManager.update(AssetManager.java:373)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/tile1.jpg
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncResult.get(AsyncResult.java:46)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.handleAsyncLoader(AssetLoadingTask.java:119)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: data/tile1.jpg
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:148)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.TextureData$Factory.loadFromFile(TextureData.java:98)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader.loadAsync(TextureLoader.java:69)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.loaders.TextureLoader.loadAsync(TextureLoader.java:41)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:70)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.assets.AssetLoadingTask.call(AssetLoadingTask.java:34)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.async.AsyncExecutor$2.call(AsyncExecutor.java:58)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data\tile1.jpg (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:222)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:145)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: include the entire exception, it should contain the cause.

Comment: I added the entire exception to my post.

Comment: may be you forgot to put this line `assetManager.finishLoading();`after loading all assets.

Comment: `File not found: data\tile1.jpg` should say enough. If you are certain the file is at the correct location and correctly names (case sensitive), then check your setup and make sure that you've set the working directory correctly. Otherwise create a test project using the setup utility and verify it runs in there.

Answer (score 0):

When you are working with Eclipse make sure the asset folder is declared as source folder in the project properties.

Comment: Should be a comment.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stackoverflow, but now I know it better